# SQL select @variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple SQL statement that is to get the first rowid from question, but it gives an error thanks to too many items return. So how can I fix it ?

```
    DECLARE @first_id int  

select @first_id = (SELECT row_number() over (order by id) as id FROM question)
```

`SELECT @first_id = id FROM question` >> this syntax works fine but not what I want from query result.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know you can cast vote. See [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/187824). Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
set @first_id = (SELECT top 1 id FROM question order by id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the ROW_NUMBER or just the id field itself?
If it is the id field it is simple:

```
SELECT @first_id = MIN(id) FROM question
```

Comment: yes i do need to use row_number because actually i don't order by id but by an alias column which counts all the vote for questions from other table, i just want to simplify the problem.

Comment: Can you give more details then please? For example what is that alias column? Sorry but I still can't get why you need ROW_NUMER? Because the first ROW_NUMBER will be always 1 whatever your data is.